# How do I efficiently trace nested function calls in C?

Tags: c

When reading a large C program or library, what is a good method for traversal of nested functions across many source files and directories?

Often a function declared in one C source file will simply redirect to another function declared in another C file, which may actually redirect once again.

Presently, I just grep for the next function in the chain to find its declaration, but there must be a more efficient way.

NOTE: I am explicitly not asking about how to trace the program flow at run time or a debugger.  I am only asking about reading the source.

Comment: Use an IDE, and then right click -> "go to definition"?

Comment: to step through the code using gdb, have all the source files available (and preferably stepping through a program where all the source files were compiled and linked with `-g` (or for gdb use `-ggdb`)  then all definitions/declarations/etc are available for display, jumping to, etc

Comment: Looks like a duplicate. Google "c code call graph", first links are on SO.

Comment: if you are using linux, use cscope

Comment: "code graph" seems to be the phrase I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net)

> Cscope is a developer's tool for browsing source code. It has an impeccable Unix pedigree, having been originally developed at Bell Labs back in the days of the PDP-11. Cscope was part of the official AT&T Unix distribution for many years, and has been used to manage projects involving 20 million lines of code!

This is a short introduction to the tool: [cscope tutorial](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse451/12sp/tutorials/tutorial_cscope.html)

A few things that cscope can do for you is:

1. Find a function definition
2. Search a C symbol
3. Find functions calling any function
4. Find egrep pattern
5. Find and replace string across the source code

If needed you can use it along with vim or emacs editor. That increases the productivity even further. When used together you can use any of cscope features directly from within the code. An example is jumping to the definition of a function. It will do much more than what you require.
**How to use Cscope with Vim**

It is simple and just a matter of few commands.

1. First create cscope database. It make take sometime depending on the no of files in your source tree. In the subsequent launches it will launch quickly.

   `$cscope -R -b`
   Now you can search anything either directly from cscope's interactive window by launching it as `cscope -d` or search from vim editor itself.
2. Suppose you are in file main.c and you have another file functions.c. In main you are calling a function func() the definition of which you want to search. In the main.c type the following command

   `:cs find g func`
   This will take you directly to the definition of function in whichever file it is in your source tree.
3. You can also configure keyboard shortcuts if you are tired of typing

I am attaching a link to vim cscope tutorial where you can find more on this:

[cscope vim basics](https://a0gustinus.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/browsing-source-code-in-linux-vimcscope/)

[cscope with vim tutorial](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html)

To do more you can use [ctags](https://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags/) along with the other two. Vim + cscope + ctags is very powerful.

Refer the [man page](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_man_page.html) to learn more

Answer (score 0):

Though not limited to that feature, [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), together with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), is able to draw interactive [call graphs and caller graphs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) in its generated HTML documentation.

Comment: In my interaction with Doxygen I have learnt that we need to add special documentation blocks for it to generate documentation. I believe that would be true for generating graphs as well. Correct me if I am missing something here

Comment: This is not a need. Doxygen does a great job extracting as much as it can from undocumented code.